# What does a web API entails if it's licensed under MIT? Do I have to credit the API if I use it in my app?

Tags: licensing, mit, copyright, api

I have trouble understanding if a web api must be credited if it's under the MIT license. I'm technically only calling the API so I'm not modify the API code. It seems to my understanding that it is not required to credit the API. Is this understanding correct?